# Prove $A\cap B=\emptyset\land C\subseteq A\cup\overline{B}\to C\subseteq\overline{B}$ using set operations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Prove that $$A\cap B=\emptyset\land C\subseteq A\cup\overline{B}\to C\subseteq\overline{B}$$ using set operations.

My proof:

\begin{align*}
C&\subseteq A\cup\overline{B}\\
&=(A\cup\overline{B})\cap(B\cup\overline{B})\\
&=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap\overline{B})\cup(\overline{B}\cap B)\cup(\overline{B}\cap\overline{B})\\
&=\emptyset\cup(A\cap\overline{B})\cup\emptyset\cup\overline{B}\\
&=\overline{B}\cup(A\cap\overline{B})\\
&=\overline{B}.
\end{align*}

Therefore $C\subseteq\overline{B}$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yup, all good! Bear in mind that you've really proven $A \cup \overline{B} = \overline{B}$, and $C$ had little to do with it.

Comment: @user771918 thank you!! Well, if I have really proven that $A \cup \overline{B} = \overline{B}$ I would like to know where is the mistake, so I can correct it.

Comment: There's no mistake at all. If $C$ is a subset of $A \cup \overline{B}$, then because they're the same set, $C$ is a subset of $\overline{B}$. I'm just pointing out that you've proven something stronger along the way.

Comment: @user771918 how do you know that they are the same set?

Comment: From your argument. If you remove the $C \subseteq$ part of the proof, you just get a perfectly valid proof that $A \cup \overline{B} = \overline{B}$.